# Why am I getting "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." when I run the last block of code in Jupyter?

Tags: python

Why am I getting "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." when I run the last block of code in Jupyter?

```
# Dependencies
import os
import csv

#Set lists to hold values
months = []
revenue = []
monthly_change = []

# Set path for file
bank_csv_path = os.path.join("Resources", "budget_data.csv")

# Open and read file
with open(bank_csv_path, newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    csv_header = next(csv_reader)

    # read thru each row after the header and list months
    for row in csv_reader:
        months.append(row[0])
        revenue.append(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
bank_csv_path = os.path.join("Resources", "budget_data.csv")
```

to

```
bank_csv_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Resources", "budget_data.csv")
print(bank_csv_path)
```

See if what is printed is what you expected…

Comment: It didn't work, but the path to the file is correct